# Weird behavior with "twitter.com" URL

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, docker, fedora

I have Fedora 24 installed on my PC. I am also running a Docker container for development. Each time I try to access `https://twitter.com` I can't and I get this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> This site on the company, organization or school intranet has the same
>   URL as an external website.
>
> Try contacting your system administrator. ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

After some research I am not able to find a solution. So I followed some steps in order to help you help me back:

- Ping `twitter.com` from terminal:

  ```
  $ ping twitter.com
  PING twitter.com.dev (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 127.0.53.53 (127.0.53.53): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
  64 bytes from 127.0.53.53 (127.0.53.53): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.252 ms
  64 bytes from 127.0.53.53 (127.0.53.53): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
  ```

Wait a minute? Response from `twitter.com.dev` and IP `127.0.53.53` what that hell? How can this be possible? Ok, let's try to figure it out:

- Check `/etc/hosts` in the Fedora Workstation:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/hosts
  127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
  ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
  #172.19.0.2 rperez.dev => This is a test using Docker container internal IP address
  #192.168.1.66 rperez.dev => This is a test using Fedora Workstation IP address
  127.0.0.1   rperez.dev => This is another test using "localhost" which work as well
  ```

No luck, nothing is pointing to `twitter.com.dev` so nothing is redirecting me. Keep going:

- Check `/etc/hosts` on the Docker container:

  ```
  # cat /etc/hosts 
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  192.168.1.66    dockerhost
  172.19.0.2  e59b9797ae06
  ```

No luck, nothing is pointing to `twitter.com.dev`. At this point I am out of ideas on what to check or what to fix.

The funny part is that I can access to Internet and navigate to any other site like Gmail, Microsoft, Google, News sites and so on but Twitter.

Other people at office are able to access Twitter. The difference? They are using DHCP I am not, I have setup my IP to be static.

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s31f6 
HWADDR=C8:5B:76:1A:8E:55
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s31f6
UUID=0af812a3-ac8e-32a0-887d-10884872d6c7
ONBOOT=yes
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPADDR=192.168.1.66
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
```

Any advice? If you need anything else from my side to give me an idea or clue, let me know and I will add it.

**UPDATE**

I am running the test above from work but I have tried from home and I got the same issue I believe is related to this"

- http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/2016/10/21/cyber-attack-takes-down-east-coast-netflix-spotify-twitter/92507806/
- https://www.dynstatus.com/

I will wait and if that's the issue I will delete the post

Comment: Don't delete, just post an answer.

Comment: @longneck I have found the issue but I have an extra doubt before post my answer, the network manager is adding `search dev` under `/etc/resolv.conf` why? how I can avoid this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Dyn DDoS attack. See the linked Q&A.

Comment: Clearly this is *not* a duplicate.  In the original question, a network was using a domain name they do not own as an internal domain.  In this case, the user is accidentally using a `.dev` domain because of the `search` rule

Answer (score 1):

twitter is down. Check this out

https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/10/ddos-on-dyn-impacts-twitter-spotify-reddit/